# Manually calling __doPostBack('myUpdatePanelId','mycustomeventarg')

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, .net-3.5, postback

In my Javascript I am manually calling

__doPostBack('myUpdatePanelId','mycustomeventarg')

It works fine except the EventArgs in my

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

is always empty.
Do I have to cast it to something else somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is normal. In my current project on every page call (whether or not postback)...

`e == EventArgs.Empty`

Comment: So is there no way to pass arguments you formed with JS?

Comment: __EVENTARGUMENT is a hidden field so you can use Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].

Comment: Or because you are using a server control override the Page.RaisePostBackEvent http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.raisepostbackevent.aspx